# Handling repetition for calculation in foreach PHP

Tags: php, loops, recursion, repeat

I've chance in my code to handling repetition calculation in foreach 
statement. the point is how to make recursive ?

in this code i always use same code, when there is "HSPK" the calculation will have same method (foreach), for this example i commend in "fifth calculation".

```
function sum_hspk($hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode) {


        $ssh_total = 0;

        $ssh_total_2 = 0;

        $ssh_total_3 = 0;

        $harga_analisa_hspk = 0;

        $harga_analisa_satuan = 0;


        $hspk_reference = json_decode(get_hspk_reference_uraian_by_hspk_uraian_hspk_kode($hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));

        $hspk_uraian = json_decode(get_hspk_uraian_by_kegiatan($hspk_reference->hspk_kegiatan_kode));


        foreach($hspk_uraian as $row) { // first foreach


            $hspk_uraian_koefisien = $row->hspk_uraian_koefisien;


            if($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_sumber == "SSH") { // first if

                $hspk_uraian_koefisien_ssh = $hspk_uraian_koefisien;

                $ssh = json_decode(get_ssh_detail_by_kode($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));

                $ssh_total += ($ssh->ssh_uraian_harga * $hspk_uraian_koefisien_ssh);

            } elseif($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_sumber == "HSPK") {


                $hspk_uraian_koefisien_hspk_2 = $hspk_uraian_koefisien;

                $hspk_uraian = json_decode(get_hspk_uraian_by_kegiatan($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));


                foreach($hspk_uraian as $row) { // second foreach


                    $hspk_uraian_koefisien = $row->hspk_uraian_koefisien;

                    if($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_sumber == "SSH") { // second if

                        $hspk_uraian_koefisien_ssh = $hspk_uraian_koefisien;

                        $ssh = json_decode(get_ssh_detail_by_kode($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));

                        $ssh_total_2 += ($ssh->ssh_uraian_harga * $hspk_uraian_koefisien_ssh);


                    }elseif($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_sumber == "HSPK") {


                        $hspk_uraian_koefisien_hspk_3 = $hspk_uraian_koefisien;

                        $hspk_uraian = json_decode(get_hspk_uraian_by_kegiatan($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));


                        foreach($hspk_uraian as $row) { // third foreach


                            $hspk_uraian_koefisien = $row->hspk_uraian_koefisien;

                            if($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_sumber == "SSH") {

                                $hspk_uraian_koefisien_ssh = $hspk_uraian_koefisien;

                                $ssh = json_decode(get_ssh_detail_by_kode($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));

                                $ssh_total_3 += ($ssh->ssh_uraian_harga * $hspk_uraian_koefisien_ssh);


                            }else if($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_sumber == "HSPK") {

                                $hspk_uraian_koefisien_hspk_4 = $hspk_uraian_koefisien;

                                $hspk_uraian = json_decode(get_hspk_uraian_by_kegiatan($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));


                                foreach ($hspk_uraian as $row) { // fourth foreach


                                    $hspk_uraian_koefisien = $row->hspk_uraian_koefisien;

                                    if($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_sumber == "SSH") {

                                        $hspk_uraian_koefisien_ssh = $hspk_uraian_koefisien;

                                        $ssh = json_decode(get_ssh_detail_by_kode($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));

                                        $ssh_total_4 += ($ssh->ssh_uraian_harga * $hspk_uraian_koefisien_ssh);

                                    }elseif($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_sumber == "HSPK") {

                                        // fifth handling

                                    } // end fourth if


                                } // end fourth foreach

                                $harga_analisa_satuan = ((($ssh_total_4) * 0.15) + ($ssh_total_4));

                                $harga_analisa_hspk = ($harga_analisa_satuan * $hspk_uraian_koefisien_hspk_3);

                                $ssh_total_3 += $harga_analisa_hspk;


                            } // end third if


                        } // end third foreach

                        $harga_analisa_satuan = ((($ssh_total_3) * 0.15) + ($ssh_total_3));

                        $harga_analisa_hspk = ($harga_analisa_satuan * $hspk_uraian_koefisien_hspk_3);

                        $ssh_total_2 += $harga_analisa_hspk;


                    }; // end second if


                } // end second foreach


                $harga_analisa_satuan = ((($ssh_total_2) * 0.15) + ($ssh_total_2));

                $harga_analisa_hspk = ($harga_analisa_satuan * $hspk_uraian_koefisien_hspk_2);

                $ssh_total += $harga_analisa_hspk;

            } // end first if



        } // end first foreach


        $harga_analisa_hspk = ((($ssh_total) * 0.15) + ($ssh_total));

        return $harga_analisa_hspk;


    } // end function
```

example execution that function:

```
$test = sum_hspk('01.04');
echo $test;
```

Comment: Recursion means that you just call a function within itself. So why not writing `sum_hspk($input)` within the function `sum_hspk`?

Comment: @NicoHaase thanks your feedback, the technique has describe by ben :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a recursive function, you need to think about what is the base case, and what you want to obtain (ssh_total) from the function. In this case, sum_hspk calculates **ssh_total** from "SSH" & "HSPK". "SSH" is your base case and you directly calculate the value. But for the "HSPK", it depends on "SSH" and "HSPK", therefore, you need to make a top-down approach until the base case "SSH" found. You need to call sum_hspk in "HSPK" conditions.

You should make this change to make recursive.

```
function get_ssh_total($row) {

    $ssh_total = 0;

    $hspk_uraian_koefisien = $row->hspk_uraian_koefisien;

    if ($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_sumber == "SSH") {

        $hspk_uraian_koefisien_ssh = $hspk_uraian_koefisien;

        $ssh = json_decode(get_ssh_detail_by_kode($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));

        $ssh_total = ($ssh->ssh_uraian_harga * $hspk_uraian_koefisien_ssh);

    }
    else if ($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_sumber == "HSPK") {

        $hspk_uraian_koefisien_hspk_2 = $hspk_uraian_koefisien;

        $hspk_uraian = json_decode(get_hspk_uraian_by_kegiatan($row->hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));

        foreach($hspk_uraian as $row) {

            $ssh_total_2 += get_ssh_total($row);

        }

        $harga_analisa_satuan = ((($ssh_total_2) * 0.15) + ($ssh_total_2));

        $harga_analisa_hspk = ($harga_analisa_satuan * $hspk_uraian_koefisien_hspk_2);

        $ssh_total += $harga_analisa_hspk;

    }

    return $ssh_total;

}

function sum_hspk($hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode) {


    $ssh_total = 0;

    $ssh_total_2 = 0;

    $ssh_total_3 = 0;

    $harga_analisa_hspk = 0;

    $harga_analisa_satuan = 0;


    $hspk_reference = json_decode(get_hspk_reference_uraian_by_hspk_uraian_hspk_kode($hspk_uraian_ssh_hspk_kode));

    $hspk_uraian = json_decode(get_hspk_uraian_by_kegiatan($hspk_reference->hspk_kegiatan_kode));


    foreach($hspk_uraian as $row) { // first foreach

        $ssh_total += get_ssh_total($row);

    } // end first foreach


    $harga_analisa_hspk = ((($ssh_total) * 0.15) + ($ssh_total));

    return $harga_analisa_hspk;


} // end function
```

Comment: when i try with a few modification, i face a lot error and calculation not exact, thanku Ben.

Comment: I just made an edit. If you still get the miscalculation, it may because of my misunderstand. You may need to explain what the result you want to have and explain what error you catch.

Comment: big thanks my brother @Ben, you solve it. i made my own code, but i don't know how to summary it lol.